# how to give smooth transaction in iPad when we change landscape to portrait or portrait to landscape

Tags: html, css, ipad, getuikit

I designed iPad based website with pure HTML and CSS, everything work pretty good, but only one thing that I have noticed and it is about the smoothness when we change device view(From landscape to Portrait or reverse) its change with little jerk.

Below tags that I have added only in  part other than else set from CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this is fixed with simple meta tag. :-)

\

Comment: this is what need to add in head tag.

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [CSS3 Transitions](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/html5/#toc-css3-transitions)? You will find that iPhone and iPad's have hardware acceleration support for CSS3 transitions. Many of the mobile widget frameworks such as JQuery Mobile and Sencha support this.

Also, [this link](http://elliotjaystocks.com/blog/css-transitions-media-queries/) shows some resizing and format changing transformations that may help smooth out your application.

Comment: I Have not use any transitions, when we change device view(like From landscape to Portrait) it is automatic set base on the resolutions which is I have set through css (like for lands scape media all and (max-width: 1600px) and (min-width: 1024px) and for portrait media all and (max-width: 800px) and (min-width: 768px)